# Looking for a peer reviewed article that details the benefits of a physics simulation within interactive media

Tags: physics, simulations

I'm hoping this is the correct place to ask this question as it is video game related and can be seen as a key ingredient in modern game development.

Does anyone know of a peer reviewed article that details the benefits of incorporating a physics simulation into interactive media (such as video games)?

I can find books with a few remarks in their introduction (no more than a couple of sentences) but nothing substantial.

Comment: Pretty much all major games are, essentially, physics simulations. So are you talking about the benefits of incorporating a 3rd party physics library as opposed to creating one yourself? Or the benefits of attempting to simulate physics accurately rather than via simple approximations? Or the benefits of having any sort of physics in a game? (Which is somewhat circular because as my first sentence states, often the game is designed to simulate some aspect of a real of fantasy world, making it intrinsically a physics simulation of sorts.)

Comment: Or maybe you are refering to projects like [this one](http://fold.it/portal/) ?

Comment: I think you're having trouble because, like Kylotan has pointed out, your question isn't very specific and in general, a peer reviewed piece will be very focused. Who's benefiting from it? What kind of study are you looking for? An article about physics, psychology, etc. What are the books you found? Those might be a good example as to what you're looking for exactly.

Comment: _Or the benefits of having any sort of physics in a game?_  I understand that it is a broad topic but a review of the general benefits it brings would be most helpful.  If you talk about a game being intrinsically a physics simulation of sorts then this should spark some debate within the academic side of the game development industry (Game Developers Conference, etc.) about their use, purpose and the benefits they bring in that regard. If pushed I would be happy with an article that focused on player immersion.

Comment: It's still unclear what could possibly be said to this. If I make a text adventure I don't think about "the benefits of incorporating words", and if I make a platform game I don't think about "the benefits of incorporating gravity". These are just requisite parts of the creation, not optional aspects added for their 'benefits'. Either the game requires them, or it doesn't. If you want to talk about why players might *prefer* games with real-world physics simulation in them, that's likely to be a subjective matter.

Comment: I think the ubiquity of physics is not in question here.  To use your text adventure analogy, you would still consider the eloquence of the language to convey a sense of immersion and narrative.  In the context of a physics simulation, a review of its use in games and how it benefits elements of game design would be ideal.  Essentially it improves A.I., animation, collision detection, HCI, etc.  It would therefore stand to reason that there must be something in the literature that acknowledges this, other than it is just essential.

Comment: Suggesting that physics is used to "improve" various features is like saying meat is used to improve hamburgers. Either a physically simulated aspect was required or it wasn't. You can't make Super Mario without jumping forces and gravity, and you can't make realistic racing games without velocity and momentum. To that extent simulated physics makes certain types of game possible but that's a bit self-evident for a peer-reviewed paper. I'm sure there are many physics papers out there but it's not going to be about "pros/cons of adding physics to a game".

Comment: Do http://graphics.cs.cmu.edu/nsp/course/15-869/papers/PhysicsAnimation_EG11.pdf and http://holzkorn.com/works/portf/psig.pdf help you?

Comment: @Dan.  The first paper does indeed help, thank you.  The second article does not appear to have been published?

Comment: @user1423893 But you can check the biblography of that document, it cites a lot of published papers relevant to this area I guess

Comment: @Kylotan I can understand your response as I am probably being too vague.  If we consider the first of the papers in the link given by Dan it provides an excellent account of how improvements in physics simulation have changed the way we now approach character animation.  Granted, it maybe have been envisaged since the 80's but the evolution of physics engines/simulations have only recently allowed us to apply this technique.

Comment: @Dan Indeed but a close inspection would find the majority of these references cite websites and there is little else pertaining to physics simulations when reading the abstracts of the remaining articles.

Comment: @user1423893: indeed, there are likely to be a few papers on specific areas like that, where one particular part of the game can be implemented differently. (Though it's possibly overstating it to say it's changed the way we now approach character animation - the paper does say *"commercial frameworks still resort to kinematics-based approaches when it comes to animating active virtual characters"*, after all.) But I don't think you'll find anything about the more general topic of *"the benefits of a physics simulation within interactive media"*, that's all.

Comment: Does this question have anything to do with developing a game?

Answer (score 1):

You should check the proceedings of the relevant conferences in the area of Computer Graphics such as SIGGRAPH, SIGGRAPH Asia, SCA and I3D. They all have tracks about physically based animation and most of the papers will have an introduction / related work about physically base animation.

To make things easier, [this website](http://www.physicsbasedanimation.com/collections/) does actually links the most relevant papers about physically based animation in the conferences I mentioned.

You could also look for surveying papers about physics simulations in fluids and character animation, they should contain information about the benefits of this approach. Here you have two that might help you: http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~jtan34/downloads/scienceInChina.pdf and http://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/docs/00/07/32/49/PDF/RR-3441.pdf

Comment: Thank you.  Physically based animation is only one aspect dramatically improved in terms of the evolution of physics simulations. The first article you linked in the comments to my post has an excellent introductory review and should suffice in this regard.